# SQL- Statements

Tags: sql, ms-access

Check this SQL and find the error .

I'm working on Microsoft Access.

This is the question :

"For each member of academic staff who spends more than 6 hours teaching any subject list the member of academic staff last name, the subject title and the number of hours."

```
Select A.LName, R.Subject ID, R.Number of hours
From AcademicStaff As A, Role As R
where Number of hours>6;
```

Comment: You can save yourself some trouble by not allowing spaces in column names.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized. It would interest no one but the few ones doing this exact homework/assignment.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
   A.[LName], 
   R.[Subject ID], 
   R.[Number of hours] 
 FROM 
   AcademicStaff AS A, Role AS R 
 WHERE 
   R.Field1 = A.Field1,
   R.[Number of hours] > 6
```

Comment: I bet this answer will get 0 grade in the assigment.

Comment: Maybe not 0, but the spaces are not the only problem of the query. The cartesian product is the other.

Answer (score 0):

first thing, spaces are not allowes in database object names, so it is good practice, in design-time, to make sure your tables'names do not include space. in this case try to enclose your tables'names between square brackets [].

also depending on the DBMS some words may be reserved, exemple, the word role is a reserved sql keyword used to create roles with DCL statements. in this case i am not sure if this will raise an error in Access db.

you also need to specify where the column "Number" comes from. the table alias or the full table name

try something like:

```
Select A.LName, R.[Subject ID], R.[Number of hours]
From AcademicStaff A, Role R
where R.[Number of hours]>6;
```